# A novice needs some help setting up relations between tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Hi guys i'm new to ruby and i need some help:
I set up three tables in ruby, here are the models:

Class User:

```
 coding: utf-8

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :password, presence: true, confirmation: {strict: true}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
    validates :telephone, uniqueness: true, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }, presence: true, length: { minimum: 9, maximum: 9 }
    validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 30 }, format: { with: /^[\w\s-]*/u, multiline: true,
                                                                              message: 'only allows letters' }
   has_many :users_valorations
   has_many :valoraions, through: :users_valorations
end
```

Class valoration:

```
class Valoration < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :points, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
   validates :category, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4, maximum: 30 }, format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z\ ]+\z/,
                                                                              message: 'only allows letters' }
   has_many :users_valorations
   has_many :users, through: :users_valorations
end
```

Class UsersValoraion

```
class UsersValoration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :valoration
end
```

schema.rb:

```
  ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150708212501) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "telephone"
    t.string   "password"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users_valorations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "valoration_sender_id"
    t.integer  "valoration_target_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",           null: false
  end

  add_index "users_valorations", ["valoration_sender_id"], name: "index_users_valorations_on_valoration_sender_id"
  add_index "users_valorations", ["valoration_target_id"], name: "index_users_valorations_on_valoration_target_id"

  create_table "valorations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "points"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "time"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

All the classes were generated by scaffold and now I just want to make this:

->When you create a valoration you have to select who sends it and who will receive it, and that data will be saved in the UsersValoration table
->list all valorations with a link to the user that sent them.

I'm pretty new so any help is welcome

Comment: in users_valorations table,add user_id and valoraion_id column for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you need to operate before or after creation of UserValoration.

ActiveRecord provides callbacks to do something during object life cycle. You can find more information here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html.

Comment: Thaks, i'll read it, but is the relationshio stablished ok? do i need to set the foreign_key option in the UsersGeneration model?

Comment: No you don't. The thing you might need to do is to add a column to `users_valorations` table called something like `type` that will indicate if a user is sender or reciever.